# React video element is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

I am trying to put video background on my site but when I put video tag to my react script it start endlessly loading on Firefox and when I try it on chrome it shows the video at 0 seconds I've tried `.mp4` and `.mov` formats without success.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import LogginScreen from "./components2/LogginScreen";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LogginScreen></LogginScreen>
        <video controls autoPlay loop muted>
          <source src="hd1992.mov" type="video/mov"></source>
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the console for both firefox and chrome? If yes please edit your post and add them in there so we can help you better.

Comment: no there is no errors in console or in web inspect tools

Comment: i tryed play video linked from YouTube and everything working correctly when i use iframe but i need it to be a backgraund so this is pointless.

Comment: i do not know why but when I put this code in JavaScript file it work                                                                                       `<video autoplay muted loop name="media">
          <source
            src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4"
            type="video/mp4"
          ></source>
        </video>`

Comment: it seems like the only way how i can play video is by linking it

Comment: Then its probably a file import issue, try importing the file to a variable and then referencing the variable in the `src` prop.

Comment: still nothing`this.ref = "vid.mov"; <video controls autoPlay muted loop name="media" playsInline>
          <source src={this.ref} type="video/mov"></source>
        </video>`

Comment: I've added an answer below, providing a working example, that may solve your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related both to the video file type `.mov` and the way you import your video.

Try to change your type attribute to `type="video/mp4"` even though it's a `.mov` and import your video like below:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import LogginScreen from "./components2/LogginScreen";
import myVideo from "./hd1992.mov";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LogginScreen></LogginScreen>
        <video controls autoPlay loop muted>
          <source src={myVideo} type="video/mp4"></source>
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mestorf-h8sx5) is a working example.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I have no idea why but when I do `<video src='video url' />` it doesn't work. But then, when I imported it just like you did, it works, thanks man